# C# Help, I am a beginner in C#, need help in some programming

Tags: c#, image, button, combobox

I have tried it many times and I failed. There are 2 big yachts available for rental, but when the user select the first big yacht, the button(picture) will turn black and there will be a combo box listing there saying "Big Yacht 1 Booked". However, when I keep on clicking on the bigyachtbutton which is "bigyacht1", the "Big Yacht 1 Booked" text kept spamming and I need to do the same for bigyacht2. Able to return (which is remove from the combobox) by just clicking the button Return. Need some help here please!!!! I need to have a return system for my yacht rental but I am unsure whether my coding is right.[![The Image below is the programming I did for my rental system for yacht. When a yacht is selected, the image will turn black and the button itself with the image will work only once. I want it to work the same with other yacht buttons as well][1]][1] PLEASE HELP

```
private void bigyacht1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bigyacht1.CanSelect)
    {
        bigyacht1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.big_yacht_BLACK;
        bigyachtcomboBox.Items.Add(bigyachtcomboBox.Text = "Big Yacht 1 Booked");

    }
    else
    {
        bigyachtreturnButton.Select();
        bigyachtcomboBox.Text = "";
        bigyacht1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.aluminum_mega_yacht_semi_displacement_hull_21287_6323513;

    }
    bigyacht1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.aluminum_mega_yacht_semi_displacement_hull_21287_6323513;


}

private void bigyachtreturnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bigyachtcomboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

}
```

Comment: Why do you set the BackgroundImage another time after the if-else-block?

Comment: Please review your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could set a bool flag the first time the button is clicked and check the flag before executing this part of code again:

Class variable:

```
private bool yacht1booked = false;
```

in the click-method:

```
if (bigyacht1.CanSelect)
{
    if (!yacht1booked)
    {
        bigyacht1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.big_yacht_BLACK;
        bigyachtcomboBox.Items.Add(bigyachtcomboBox.Text = "Big Yacht 1 Booked");
        yacht1booked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking for texts in a list is not more nearly done. What if it's translated? A typo fixed? Many more places to go wrong

Comment: Thanks Dave but I am still unable to get rid of the "Big Yacht 1 Booked" when I pressed the Return Button. It still stays there, how is it so?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen you're right, I didn't think about that. I edited the answer.

Comment: @Kevin123 set a breakpoint to the first line and debug through the code. This often helps a lot in understanding where such behaviour comes from

Comment: and I forgot you have to declare the flag as a class variable. Silly me. It's early in the morning where I live ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave, but now when I click on my bigyacht1 (a button with the picture), the image doesnt change after editing.

Comment: it should change the first time. do you want to change it more often?

Comment: depending on what behaviour you exactly want, you might have to check the flag at another line in the code, for example inside the if block or after the image is set.

Comment: It didn't change for the first time, the image still remains the same (without going to black and white). It is a return system, when it clicks, it comes black but when people return, it becomes not black. :) I am still unsure though, sorry, im starting learning it only for a few months.

Comment: as I asked in a comment to your question: why do you set an image in every case after the if-else-block?

Comment: It changes now for the first time, but however when returning the yacht, the image doesn't go back to normal. (It requires a click on the button), but I want the image to automatically return to the normal image after the user returns the yacht.

Comment: come on, I don't want to write the application for you. You don't set an image in `bigyachtreturnButton_Click`, so how should it change?

Comment: I deleted the part where there is an image after every case of the if-else block. Sorry, beginner here so I need a lot of help.

Comment: Everything looks fine now, just that the part where I returned the yacht, the selection inside the combobox still have the word "Big Yacht 1 Booked", still unable to get rid of it after pressing return.

Comment: well, as I said: if you don't tell the image to go back to normal in the `bigyachtreturnButton_Click`-method, the image simply won't go back to normal when clicking on the "Return" button

Comment: the image is fine now, it is the word now. "Big Yacht 1 Booked" cannot be get rid of after clicking bigyachtreturnButton.

Comment: well I guess you just don't remove the text in the method